# How to change date format on ios?

Tags: ios, date, format

I have a date like this : Mon, 04 Jun 2012 14:13:00 GMT
and want to delete the time displayed so that I can have something like this : Mon, 04 Jun 2012

I tried the code below :

```
NSString *dateTex = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"date"];
NSLog(@"the object value is:%@",dateTex);    

//changing dates format
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];    
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateTex];
[dateFormatter release];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter2 setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy"];
NSString *dateText = [dateFormatter2 stringFromDate:date];
[dateFormatter2 release];
NSLog(@"the object value is:%@",dateText);
```

The date is parsed from an xml file and saved in the `NSString dateTex`. Then I am trying to change the format and save the new date on `NSString dateText`. However when I try to print the dateText variable, I get `the object value is (null)`.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below code :

```
NSString *dateTex = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"date"];
NSLog(@"the object value is:%@",dateTex);    

 //changing dates format
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"]; 
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateTex];
[dateFormatter release];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy"];

NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];

NSString *my_date_string = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
//my_date_string returns like value Tue 05 jun 2012
```

Welcome!

Comment: Why are you set the `NSDateFormatterShortStyle` and `NSLocale`?